# Converting string data type 123 to INT, how solve bad64INT?

Tags: google-bigquery

SELECT
station_id,
name,
number_of_rides as num_rides_starting_at_station
FROM
(SELECT start_station_id,
COUNT(*) Number_of_rides
FROM`bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips`
GROUP BY start_station_id
)
AS station_num_trips
INNER JOIN `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations`
ON CAST(station_id AS int64) =start_station_id --used CAST convert Station_id to INT
ORDER BY station_num_trips.Number_of_rides desc

Station_id is string, start_station_id is an int, so I tried to convert the data type to of Station ID into a INT to run the inner join, but I get Bad int64 value: 581211b2-4e42-48f2-8a8f-5f968cb1...  from BigQuery

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some of the values in Station ID are not actual integers (you example has dashes and letters).

You could do the opposite and cast the integer into a string, or use the SAFE_CAST instead for the station_id which will product a NULL instead of an error for invalid castings.